# PHP eval not working - alternative to eval

Tags: php, class, interface, eval

I created a set of classes for creating a database connection and set of select queries etc and it works perfectly fine. After that I took it a step further by creating a set of interfaces and adjusting my classes accordingly. The idea is that when I want to create a connection to my database that the code would look like this: [$this->Function = new Connection(new _MySqli);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp42q.jpg)

Because of the way I did this, my connection queries are returned as strings (because the "new _MySqli" part defines what code I use to connect to my database etc). For this I'm using EVAL to try and run my strings as code but it does nothing.

Is there another way I can run my strings as code ([seen in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cBca.jpg)) without having to rework my code completely? I can always just do my if else checks in all my classes but would rather try and keep my code clean.

Keep in mind, I just started learning classes and interfaces so feel free to point out anything you noticed in my code that could have been done better or looks wrong.

Comment: Please post the actual snippet of your implementation.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel I see, why not use PDO? It supports multiple database drivers out of the box.

Comment: There's not enough information here to be able to answer your question. The screenshot helps a bit but is still not enough, and you should post actual code in the question instead of screens of it.

Comment: Hi @Xorifelse, will PDO also accommodate microsoft sql (sqlsrv)?

Comment: @Starlette Check the list of [PDO Supported database drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) SQL server is on that.

Comment: Hi @apokryfos and Xorifelse , I spent a few hours now re adjusting my working version from mysqli to pdo and got it working :) thank you.